# Issue with PHP redirect

Tags: php

I'm working on a very simple php project and I don't overcome to be well-redirected after my form submission.

I create `user` thanks to my form, then I pick-up the `user id` and I would like to be redirected on a new page with `id` include into the url.

So I have a part of my script which commit data into my database :

```
$result = 0;

if (! $error)
{
    $object->nom = $nom;
    $object->prenom = $prenom;
    $datenaissance = dol_mktime(0, 0, 0, GETPOST('datenaissancemonth'), GETPOST('datenaissanceday'), GETPOST('datenaissanceyear'));
    $object->datenaissance = $datenaissance;
    $object->adresse = $adresse;
    $object->country_id = GETPOST('country_id', 'int');
    $result = $object->create($user); //return int

    if ($result <= 0)
    {
        setEventMessages($object->errors, 'errors');
        $error++;
    }
}

// If no SQL error we redirect to the request card
if (! $error)
{
    $db->commit();
    $db->close();

    header("Location: ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?id='.$object->id);
    exit;
}
else
    {
    $db->rollback();
}
```

This part seems to work because when I click on `submit button` I get this url as example : `http://172.30.10.189/moduletest/card.php?id=12`

So in my script I have this second part after the first one displays previously :

```
else if ($object->id > 0)
{

    $head=product_prepare_head($object);
    $titre=$langs->trans("Fiche Identité".$object->type);

    dol_fiche_head($head, 'card', $titre, -1, $picto);

    $linkback = '<a href="'.DOL_URL_ROOT.'/moduletest/index.php'.$object->type.'">'.$langs->trans("Retour vers Accueil").'</a>';

    print '<div class="fichecenter">';
    print '<div class="fichehalfleft">';

    print '<div class="underbanner clearboth"></div>';
    print '<table class="border tableforfield" width="100%">';


    print '<tr><td class="nowrap">';
    print '<table width="100%" class="nobordernopadding"><tr><td class="nowrap">';
    print $langs->trans("BarcodeType");
    print '</td></tr>'."\n";

    // Nom
    print '<tr><td class="nowrap">';
    print $langs->trans("Nom");
    print '</td><td colspan="2">';
    print $object->nom;
    print '</td></tr>';

    // '''other fields'''

    print "</table>\n";
    print '</div>';

    print '</div></div>';
    print '<div style="clear:both"></div>';

    dol_fiche_end();
}

// End of page
llxFooter();
```

But nothing appears according to my object into the new page. None array or object fields.

Do you think that something is false on my way to do that ?

Comment: you have to get the id using `$_GET` and then do db operation

Comment: So I have to modify `else if ($object->id > 0) ` by `else if ($_GET['id] > 0)` ?

Comment: do not include user id in the url as this can be revealing, set a session variable instead or use a hash, a bit of obscurity.

Comment: @deadpool yes but that is not enough.if you going to use `$object->x` then you have to create the object again

Comment: @coderodour I have to see How I can do that, I'm very new with PHP langage.

Comment: @FastSnail Ok I will see more about this kind of things.

Comment: What I don't understand is : if I wrote this code : `else
{
    if ($id > 0)
    {
        print $_GET['id'];`}} it displays my ID, but my script if I replace for example : `print $object->nom;` by `print $_GET['nom'];` doesn't work